# How to create the "indexes" required for NSIndexPath:indexPathWithIndexes:length:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

The class method to create an index path with one or more nodes is:

```
+ (id)indexPathWithIndexes:(NSUInteger *)indexes length:(NSUInteger)length
```

How do we create the "indexes" required in the first parameter?

The documentation listed it as *Array of indexes to make up the index path* but it is expecting a (NSUinteger *).

To create an index path of 1.2.3.4, is it simply an array of [1,2,3,4] ?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You are correct. You might use it like this:

```
NSUInteger indexArr[] = {1,2,3,4};

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:indexArr length:4];
```

Comment: sorry for newbie question: do i need to [indexSet release] after use?

Comment: @Steve Not in this case. You will find the answer to this an all Cocoa-related memory management issues in the Memory Management Programming Guide for Cocoa (http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html). Because `indexPathWithIndexes:length` doesn't have 'new', 'copy', or 'alloc' in the selector, the Cocoa rules specify that it returns an autoreleased instance.

Answer (score 44):

On iOS, you can also use this method from [NSIndexPath UIKit Additions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/) (declared in UITableView.h):

```
+ (NSIndexPath*) indexPathForRow:(NSUInteger)row inSection:(NSUInteger)section
```

Comment: Aha!  Documentation (of sorts) for the "undocumented API" about which I asked in another Q.  Thanks!  :)

Comment: it's very well documented: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html, however it is only available on the iphone (UIKit).

Comment: This method is declared in NSIndexPath, not UITableView.

Comment: The above method is identical to the following code: `NSUInteger indexes[] = {section, row}; [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:indexes length:2];` (If you are targeting both iOS and Mac platforms, the NSIndexPath UIKit extensions are not available, so you will need to use this approach instead.)

Answer (score 7):

You assumption is correct. It's as simple as a C array of NSUInteger. The length parameter is the number of elements in the indexes array.

Arrays in C are often identified as a pointer (in this case NSUInteger *) with a length parameter or a known terminator such as \0 for C strings (which is just a char array).

Answer (score 3):

I did this in 2 lines of code

```
 NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];   
 for (int i = firstIndexYouWant; i < totalIndexPathsYouWant; i++) [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
```

Short, clean, and readable.  Free code, don't knock it.

Comment: i will break the 2nd lines into multiple, hurt my eyeys