# What's the exact meaning of the indexPath.section?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

From Apple's documentation about the method indexPathForRow, I am not clear on when and how to use indexPath.section and I am not clear on what exactly means a 'section'. I am new to iPhone development, can someone please help me explain 'section' a little?

From UIKit’s documentation:

> `row`
>
> An index number identifying a row in a UITableView object in a section identified by section.
>
> `section`
>
> An index number identifying a section in a UITableView object.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image]

Hope you understand what is mean by a section. I think row you already know. If you have any doubts post as a comment.

Comment: Trisha, thanks a lot for the explanation, especially the drawing you made. The drawings made me immediately understand what the section means and what are the rows in a particular section. Really appreciate ur great help! :)

Comment: Just wanted to point out (for anyone who finds this thread in the future) that index starts at 0. So, the 1st section in that diagram would actually be 0, same with the second which is actually 1, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can have **sections** of **rows**. There always is at least one section for a table view. You can use `numberOfSections` method to change this. Similarly, `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` tells how many rows are in the given section. And finally `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` gives the cell given the row and section. For example, in the contacts application, each alphabet is a section. Its rows are all names starting with that letter. For example "S" will have "Samuel", "Sarah". Similarly, "A" will have "Ali", "Alex". I suggest you read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html) thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks debuggerman! :) I will read the documentation through. i picked Trisha's answer as the correct answer though yours is correct and helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

The section and the row of an index path is a special case (actually an [extension to NSIndexPath for UIKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html), see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181432/how-to-create-the-indexes-required-for-nsindexpathindexpathwithindexeslength)). For a given NSIndexPath indexPath

```
[indexPath indexAtPosition:0];
```

is the same as

```
[indexPath section];
```

and

```
[indexPath indexAtPosition:1];
```

is the same as

```
[indexPath row];
```

This makes it more intuitive to handle paths in table views which have sections and a given number of rows for each section.

Answer (score 0):

Each table has sections, and rows within that section. `indexPath.row` and `indexPath.section` reference the different parts accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**IndexPath**

It is a position(section and row) inside TableView

```
TableView <- Section <- Row
```

```
IndexPath {
    let section: Int 
    let row: Int 
}
```